# OracleJet Splitbutton get select event value

Tags: knockout.js, split-button, oracle-jet

Using the Oraclejet framework, I was trying to make a splitbutton which has only 2 options. How can I differentiate them so that each go to their own function? Or how can I paste the text of selected to function as parameter?

It was something like this

```
<div id="dialogWrapper" style="position:relative; max-height:1%; max-width:1%;">
 <button id="printPdf" style="margin-right:6px;"data-bind="
                        ojComponent: {component: 'ojButton',            
                                      menu:'#choices'
                                      }"/>
```

The menu inside:

```
 <ul id="choices" style="display:none"
      data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojMenu', select: print//here both of them call to same function}">
 <li id="PDF">
         a href="#"><span class=""></span>PDF</a>
        </li>
        <li id="Excel">
        <a href="#"><span class=""></span>Excel</a>
     </li>     
  </ul> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by using some parameters of the selection handler function:

I've recreated the example above and tested this code:

```
<div id="dialogWrapper" style="position:relative; max-height:1%; max-width:1%;">
 <button id="printPdf" style="margin-right:6px;"data-bind="
                        ojComponent: {component: 'ojButton',            
                                      menu:'#printOptionsList',
                                      label: 'Print Option'
                                      }"/>
 <ul id="printOptionsList" style="display:none"
      data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojMenu', select:printOptionHandler}">
 <li id="selPdf"><a href="#"><span class="oj-menu-item"></span>PDF</a></li>
 <li id="selExcel"><a href="#"><span class="oj-menu-item"></span>Excel</a>
     </li>     
  </ul> 
 </div>
```

as for the script part, I've added the printOptionHandler to the main knockout object:

```
self.printOptionHandler = function(event,ui){
            var sel = ui.item.children("a").text();
            //alert('option selected: ' + sel);
            if (sel == "Excel") {
                alert("calling Excel function");
            } else if (sel == "PDF"){
                alert ("calling PDF function");
            }
        };
```

Does this render the desired output on your side as well?

Comment: It worked perfectly. But can you explain for me  a bit about "ui.item.children" ? What does that mean

Comment: This is the example I've seen in the jet CookBook for accessing the menu's current state: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/uiComponents-menuButton-menuButtonComponent.html

Comment: the jQuery ui.item.children([selector]) searches through the selected item (in this case we have an <li> element selected) for a target element - in our case a link element (<a>) where a text value is stored. Therefore ui.item.children("a").text() accessor.